# Undefined index: image

Tags: php

I'm trying to upload a file (image) to sql table via pathfile but I keep getting these error "undefined index : image on line 3 and line 24". I already defined the image in the userpage.  I'm not using BLOB because it consumes too much space. In my sql table, I simply set the image column as vachar. I already checked the php.ini file in xampp ,the upload is on and the maximum is 2MB upload file.Please help. tq.

Below is the userpage:

```
<?php

//useracc-test.php

//start session
session_start();



require 'connect-test.php';
include 'upload.php';

if(isset($_POST['username'])){


    $userName = $_POST['username'];
    $query = "SELECT id, name, username, telno FROM users WHERE username = ?";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $userName);
    $stmt->execute();
    $res = $stmt->get_result(); 
    $row = $res->fetch_array();
    $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
    $_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'];
    $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
    $_SESSION['telno'] = $row['telno'];

}
?>



<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function MM_jumpMenu(targ,selObj,restore){ //v3.0
  eval(targ+".location='"+selObj.options[selObj.selectedIndex].value+"'");
  if (restore) selObj.selectedIndex=0;
}
</script>
</head>



<body>
<div id="apDiv3">
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><span class="TabbedPanelsContent">
  <?php
    echo $_SESSION['id']."<br/>";
    echo $_SESSION['name']."<br/>";
    echo $_SESSION['username']."<br/>";
    echo $_SESSION['telno']."<br/>";
?>




  <?php 



 if(isset($_POST['submit']))

   {

    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $name2 = $_POST['name2'];
    $color2 = $_POST['color2'];
    $hobby2 = $_POST['hobby2'];
    $radiobtn = $_POST['radiobtn'];
    $image = $_POST['image'];




    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO useradvert (id,name2,color2,hobby2,radiobtn,image) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("isssss",$id,$name2,$color2,$hobby2,$radiobtn,$image);
    $stmt->execute();



   // $stmt->close();
   // $conn->close();

   //think of something later how to close and logout
  /*  <?php unset($_SESSION); 
    session_destroy(); ?> */
   } 


    ?>

</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
<form name="form2" 
      action="useracc-test.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <table width="500" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td>category</td>
      <td><select name="jumpMenu" id="jumpMenu" onChange="MM_jumpMenu('parent',this,0)">
        <option value="useracc-test.php" selected>Category</option>
        <option value="useracc-test.php">Members</option>
        <option value="useracc-test2-jumpmenu.php">Non-members</option>
      </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ID:</td>
      <td><input name="id" type="text" id="id" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['id']; ?>" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Name:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="name2" id="name2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Color</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="color2" id="color2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hobby</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="hobby2" id="hobby2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sex</td>
      <td>male
        <input type="radio" name="radiobtn" id="radio" value="male">
        female
        <input type="radio" name="radiobtn" id="radio2" value="female"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Image</td>
      <td><input type="file" name="image" id="image"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div align="center"></div>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
</form>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>
</body>
               </html>
```

below is the upload.php file where I run the upload script.

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image or not
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {

    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["image"]["size"] > 200000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["image"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

I'm getting error undefined index on line 3 and line 24.

error line 3 refers to below;

```
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
```

error line 24 refers to below;

```
if ($_FILES["image"]["size"] > 200000) {
```

Comment: You're trying to access `$_FILES['image']` outside `ifset($_POST['submit']`. So when the script runs before you submit the page, there's no file.

Comment: tq @Barmar. But could you point me to the direction and post your answer in the answer section. I have a limited knowledge in PHP as I'm a newbie in this field. tq.

Comment: @Barmar. I tried that previously. But unfortunately, it gives me more errors, undefined index on line 30, 35, 40 and 41. Any solution?. btw. tq for your help. I appreciate.

Comment: Which lines are those?

Comment: sorry, i pasted them back again. and enter several spaces, but i just pasted them back again as previously. now the error is if (file_exists($target_file)) { (line 39), if ($_FILES["image"]["size"] > 200000) {(line 44), if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"(line 49), && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0; (line 50). I did the same thing as you suggested previously.

Comment: What index does it say doesn't exist? Are you sure the user actually uploaded a file?

Comment: What would the directory have to do with an undefined index? Do you understand what that error message means?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index

Comment: Sorry my bad. yeah agree. I'm still sticking to the suggestion you gave me. But I just can't solve the problem.

Comment: What do `var_dump($_POST)` and `var_dump($_FILES)` show?

Comment: Do some basic debugging. When it tells you there's a problem with a variable, look at the value of the variable.

Comment: @Barmar, as I mentioned earlier, I'm a newbie, and I don't really comprehend what you are trying to say regarding var_dump etc. Basically, all the other codes work fine. The only problem is with the upload.php.

Comment: `var_dump` will show the contents of a variable. So if it's saying that `$_FILES['image']` is undefined, the first thing you should do is look at what's actually in `$_FILES`.

Comment: Simple common sense, I think.

Comment: Maybe if you can show me by correcting my mistakes in the answers section, it would be helpful since you have  the experience and have gone through this before.

Comment: How can I correct your mistakes until you answer my questions so I figure out what the problem is?

Comment: Ok. i i tried var_dump($_POST) and var_dump($_FILES) for the first time. it showed array(3) { ["username"]=> string(14) "test2@mail.com" ["password"]=> string(8) "abcd1234" ["login"]=> string(5) "Login" } array(0) { }

Comment: How do I relate this to undefined index and variables?

Comment: I just noticed something. The code you posted is in `upload.php`. But the form says `action="useracc-testphp"`, so that's where the code that processes `$_FILES['image']` should be.

Comment: I change the  action="useracc-test.php" to  action="upload.php" all the errors gone. Now I have to think a way how to migrate the codes in userpage to upload.php. I there anyone out there that is kind that can help me here? It seems im solving my own problem

Comment: sorry didn't saw ur message above ..why does my pc keeps getting late response from other users

Comment: Sorry @Barmar, didn't saw your message coming. it seems my browser or something is not alerting me when a user post comments.

Comment: So, is    action="upload.php"        the correct way? @Barmar

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but for security reasons you might want to use: `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {`

Comment: @ml2 If that's the correct name of the script, it is.

Comment: the errors are gone already, but now i can't insert the data. i have to migrate some of the scripts from userpage to upload.php. Am I correct? correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @ml2 Yes, I believe that's correct. I hope you're not expecting us to do all that work for you. You're expected to understand the basics, we'll help you fix things, but not do your work for you.

Comment: yeah.. I agree..@Barmar.

Comment: post your comments in the answer section @Barmar. So I can accept your answer just now. tq

Comment: Or I'll just accept the answer below. which did help.

Comment: Hi @Roko. I'll try your suggestion later. since i'm a newbie. aren't i suppose to use isset before ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')  ???? please correct me. tq

Comment: Someone didn't read the documentation...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit regarding...

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan: The handling of uploaded files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the code that depends on the post parameters should be inside the `if isset($_POST['submit'])` block. Otherwise, none of the other `$_POST` or `$_FILE` parameters will be set.

The other problem you're having is that you're posting to the wrong script. The form should say `action = "upload.php"`.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $target_dir = "uploads/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    // Check if image or not

    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

    // Check if file already exists
    if (file_exists($target_file)) {
        echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Check file size
    if ($_FILES["image"]["size"] > 200000) {
        echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Allow certain file formats
    if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
    && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
        echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
    // if everything is ok, try to upload file
    } else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
            echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["image"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
        } else {
            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }
    }
}
?>
```