# Image saved to folder but path not saved in sql

Tags: php, html, mysql, image

I'm trying to upload image files to my local folder (local hosting). I manage to do it. The problem is, I don't see the image path in the sql table including the rest of the data that suppose to be inserted in the table. Previously I was able to, before I messed around.  I previously made minor changes to upload.php. Even though I manage to upload image files to the local folder (the same directory as my pages). I've tried this since morning and now it's midnight.  I also get an error "Undefined index: image..line 106"  -->>

```
$image = $_POST['image'];
```

Please help.tq

Below is the upload.php.

```
   <?php


//echo var_dump($_POST);
//echo var_dump($_FILES);

session_start();



require 'connect-test.php';




if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {




    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $name2 = $_POST['name2'];
    $color2 = $_POST['color2'];
    $hobby2 = $_POST['hobby2'];
    $radiobtn = $_POST['radiobtn'];
    $image = $_FILE['image'];







        $target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    // Check if image or not    


    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

// Check if file already exists



if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["image"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["image"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}





    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO useradvert (id,name2,color2,hobby2,radiobtn,image) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("isssss",$id,$name2,$color2,$hobby2,$radiobtn,$target_file);
    $stmt->execute();


}




?>
```

Comment: and you already posted a similar question earlier http://stackoverflow.com/q/34567413/ about the same problem.

Comment: @Fred. Previously it was about undefined index. BUt now i manage to insert the image to the folder, except the path. but in the same time, i'm receiving some errors also. it's a 2 in 1 problem now.

Comment: After one problem solved previously, a new problem is created but comes with another one. it's a bit complicated

Comment: ok, well see the other answers given below. I've posted one, but that may not be enough to completely solve the problem you are now having.

Comment: if you're trying to save the path of the  file, then you're using the wrong variable. In `("isssss",$id,$name2,$color2,$hobby2,$radiobtn,$image);` you need to use `("isssss",$id,$name2,$color2,$hobby2,$radiobtn,$target_file);` as per `$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);` and is what Webster wrote in their answer. But you will still need to change this `$image = $_POST['image'];` as per what I said `$image = $_FILES['image'];`

Comment: tq u to all for the reply. i still got an error 
Notice: Undefined variable: _FILE in C:\xampp\htdocs\eventsite\upload.php on line 26

Comment: `_FILE`? you forgot the S here.

Comment: I managed to save the filepath aready in the sql table. tq. and also in the image folder. but this undefined error keeps prompting

Comment: i will update my new code above.

Comment: look at my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/34568860/1415724, I wrote 35 mins prior to this comment, it's `$_FILES` with an `S`, and not `$_FILE`. `$image = $_FILE['image'];` to `$image = $_FILES['image'];` and in my comment above too. That's why it's giving you that error.

Comment: OMG. Silly me. sorry @Free-ii-. Tq so much. And also to the rest. Tq for all the correct answers.

Comment: you're welcome, glad it worked out, *cheers*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your original post https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/34568743/1

We're dealing with `$_FILES` here and not `$_POST`.

Therefore you need to change your `$_POST` to `$_FILES` for `$image = $_POST['image'];`

Reference:

- http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Answer (score 1):

You want to insert the image's path right?
This variable already return the image's path

```
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
```

Then change this

```
$stmt->bind_param("isssss",$id,$name2,$color2,$hobby2,$radiobtn,$image);
```

to this

```
$stmt->bind_param("isssss",$id,$name2,$color2,$hobby2,$radiobtn,$target_file);
```

Comment: I upvoted this answer because it addressed the second part of the OP's issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have enctype='multpart/form-data' in the form
2. When inserting to the database, make sure you insert the file path i.e '$target_dir/filetempname'

   $imagepath = $target_dir/filetempname
3. Please insert in db only if move_uploaded is successful. Otherwise things will be empty nad security reason.

   if(move_uploaded_file is successful){
   //code to insert in db.
   }
4. We get file data using $_FILES variable not $_POST even though files are posted using post method.